# Time difference between rows after a groupby in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to group by a column called name, find the time difference between each row and then add it to a new column called: Time_diff. I tried to do the following, could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here:

`data["Time_diff"]=data.groupby('name')['Time'].diff(-1)`

I got this error:
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute '_aggregate_item_by_item'

​

Comment: Looks pretty normal to me. Can you share the data?